# Arrays Error Error "Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I'm doing my homework. I am assigned to create a Tic Tac Toe application, I've finished it but there's a small error, and I think I'm overlooking something, but I can't figure it out and need some new eyes to check it out because I think I'm looking at it for too long and missing a big concept.

```
        Random r = new Random();//Creates the number generator.
        int [][] numbers = new int [3][3]; //creates a 3x3 integer grid.
        for (int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; i++){
        for (int j=0;j<numbers[i].Length;j++){
        numbers[i][j] = r.Next(2);//Traverses the array and inputs a number between 0 and 1 here.
```

}
  }

```
        Console.WriteLine("%d|%d|%d\n",numbers[0][0],numbers[0][1],numbers[0][2]);

        Console.WriteLine("------");
        Console.WriteLine("%d|%d|%d\n",numbers[1][0],numbers[1][1],numbers[1][2]);

        Console.WriteLine("------");
        Console.WriteLine("%d|%d|%d\n",numbers[2][0],numbers[2][1],numbers[2][2]);
```

The error is in the second line. Maybe I did the int [][] numbers = new int [][]; format wrong? Please help me identify what's wrong it. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like C#. That'd be `new int[3,3]`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to C#. I misclicked it. And yes, I have tried that before, it give sme the same error: "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[*,*]' to 'int[][]'" Not sure what to do now. Please help.

Comment: Well, you'd index `numbers[i,j]` then. And you can't use `numbers[i].Length`. You could also use an array of arrays, `int[][] numberss = new int[3][];` and `for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) numbers[i] = new int[3];`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when declaring your array:

```
int [,] numbers = new int[3,3];
```

You need to change your accesses to the array also fx:

```
numbers[i,j] = r.Next(2);
```

To iterate the array you can use `numbers.GetLength(index)` method instead of `numbers.Length` and `numbers[i].Length`.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        ...
```

EDIT: If you really want to stay with your array of arrays (also called jagged arrays) you can initialize it like this:

```
 int[][] numbers = new int[3][] 
                   {   
                       new int[3],
                       new int[3],
                       new int[3]
                   };
```

Comment: I have changed the numbers[][] into numbers[i,j] but on the 4th line, "Length" gives me an error and I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Sorry, I'm very new to C# and have lots to learn. This is the error it gives "Error 1 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"